# Navigation Drawer Item icon Right Side

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I am begineer. I want to know , How to add a Item inside `Navigation Drawer` which icon will be add right side of Item Title.

Exactly I want to do like this picture.

[image: see this]

But how?
I want to add item exactly like this Youtube Item.

This is `Navigation Drawer` Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:title="Social Links">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_facebook"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_facebook"
                android:title="Facebook"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_youtube"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_youtube"
                android:title="Youtube"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_twitter"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_twitter"
                android:title="Twitter"
                />

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I also attached this code in `Manifest`:

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Comment: Rather creating menu why don't you create custom views? Use recycler view and create multiple views

Comment: try to create custom ArrayAdapter which contains TextView and ImageView

Comment: ok, But otherwise not possible?
Please give me a  link for custom views of this.
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Under res layout folder, create a layout named **menu_image.xml**. This layout is used to render image next to YouTube label.

**menu_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="6dp"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/addyourimage"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
 navigationView.getMenu().getItem(5).setActionView(R.layout.menu_image);
```

> More [Referencer](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: Hi, it's showing but how can I define my menuitem serial number? I used group there

Comment: i am not getting what your saying...can explain little more

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working. 
I just modified your code like me.
See:

`    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
//        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setActionView(R.layout.nav_menu_layout);
        Menu menuNav = navigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem facebookItem = menuNav.findItem(R.id.nav_facebook);
        facebookItem.setActionView(R.layout.nav_menu_layout);
`

Comment: Can I add you on social media?
Please.

Comment: Thanks! It's work for me.

Comment: If it is not working for you try using ImageView instead of LinearLayout to display image. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

#### Create Customized Layout As per Your Reqiurement

#### and Use it as headelLayout in NavigationView

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/...." />
```